# How to create cboden/rachet RPC implementation?

Tags: rpc, autobahn, ratchet, autobahnws, wamp-protocol

I'm learning websockets and just learned how to use sub/pub using [cboden/ratchet example push integration](http://socketo.me/docs/push) as my server and autobahnjs for my browser. my question is does ratchet or autobahn supports rpc?

If you have any sources or examples it's highly appreciated. cheers!

Comment: Ratchet implements WAMP1, which is deprecated, and does not work with current AutobahnJS nor does it provide registering of procedures. A fully WAMP2 compatible implementation in PHP is Thruway https://github.com/voryx/Thruway - I'd recommend looking at this.